# Prove that there does not exists an estimator for which the risk is $0$

Tags: mathematical-statistics, inference, loss-functions

> Let $\lbrace \mathbb{P}_\theta \rbrace_{\theta\in \Theta}, \Theta \subset \mathbb{R}$, be an identifiable parametric family of distributions with common support, where card$(\Theta)\geq 2$. Consider the family of estimators $\Delta = \lbrace \delta(\textbf{X}): \mathbb{E}_\theta \delta^2 <\infty, \theta \in \Theta \rbrace$ and the loss function $L(\theta,a)=(\theta-a)^2$. Prove that there does not exist an estimator $\delta(\textbf{X})$ for which $R(\theta,\delta)=0,\theta \in \Theta$.

So I suppose that there exists an estimator $\delta(\textbf{X})$ for which $R(\theta,\delta)=0,\theta \in \Theta$. Since the loss function is non-negative, then it concludes that $\delta(\textbf{X}) = \theta $ almost surely. I don't know if it is true, because I think that $\theta(\textbf{X})$ cannot take many values. If yes, then what can I do next to show the contradictory? I want to show that for all $x$ in $\Omega$, $f(x;\theta_1)=f(x;\theta_2)$ so it contradicts the definition of identifiable parametric family, but I am not sure how.

Comment: If $\theta$ is your parameter, can $\delta(X)=\theta$ be an estimator?

Comment: I think It can still be the parameter, the only thing that concerns me is that the estimator can take many value, which is not true?

Comment: Isn't $\delta(X)=\theta$ a contradiction?

Comment: Yes, I think so, but then why did they give so many assumptions?